# .calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Reminder) not returning list of reminder lists

Tags: ios, swift, reminders, ekeventstore

Help,
trying to get a list of the reminder lists from EventKit.
This just doesn't return anything.  If I change EKEntityType.Reminder to .Event I get the calendars(Events) so I know the code is generally good.

Thoughts

```
var eventStore = EKEventStore()

func get_calendars(completed: (([EKCalendar])->())) {
   print("in Get_Calendars")

   let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Reminder)

    for calendar in calendars as [EKCalendar] {
        // 2
        print(calendar.title)
        print(calendar.calendarIdentifier) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts.

1. Make sure you have requested access to the Reminders:

   ```
   let eventStore = EKEventStore()
   eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Reminder, completion: {
       granted, error in

       if granted {
           let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(.Reminder)

           for calendar in calendars as [EKCalendar] {
               print(calendar.title)
               print(calendar.calendarIdentifier)
           }
       }
       else {
           print("Permission denied by user")
       }
   })
   ```
2. Make sure you have at least one reminder. If you are running in the simulator, you probably don't have any reminders, and you will not see a calendar. At least, that was what I saw while testing this.

Comment: Yep I have access  to the reminders as I am currently listing all the reminders out.  And yep have a chunk of reminders titled test1, test2, test3, etc :)

Comment: ok.  I was being dumb !  I had moved code around and hadn't checked for access.   What was weird was it was working for .event type without the check.   Ghost in the machine.   Thanks Mike I really appreciate you checking my brain and making me check and check my code again.   All working now :)

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark this answer as accepted? Also, once you've granted access on a device or simulator, it doesn't ever prompt again. I had to reset the simulator during testing.